# TextBlock bind with two sources

Tags: binding, uwp

I have a TextBlock and to show translated text I use

```
x:Uid="/FileResourceName/txtControldName" Name="txtControlName"
```

(in resource file I write: txtControldName.Text = "some text") it works fine. But I would like to hide or show it depend on codebehind object and for that I use

```
Visibility="{Binding Path = IsMyControlVisible}"
```

(in that case for text I have to assign some text directly in control like Text="some text"). If I use one of this two properties everything works fine but simultaneously these two properties do not work. Is there any way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use one of this two properties everything works fine but simultaneously these two properties do not work. Is there any way to do the same?

It's not a normal behavior. There is no conflict between binding to `Visibility` property and setting text in resource file. Have you set DataContext for your Binding?

Please see the following code sample, it worked well.

[image]

```xml
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Uid="txtControldName" Visibility="{Binding IsMyControlVisible}"></TextBlock>
    <Button Content="test" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private Visibility _IsMyControlVisible;
    public Visibility IsMyControlVisible
    {
        get { return _IsMyControlVisible; }
        set
        {
            _IsMyControlVisible = value;
            RaisePropertyChange("IsMyControlVisible");
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChange(String PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMyControlVisible = IsMyControlVisible == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Please note that you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, when the property value is change, it will notify the UI.